# how to label sections in a bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, bar-chart

What is the most simple way to label all the sections?

```
x = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
y1 = np.array([2, 4, 5, 1])
y2 = np.array([1, 0, 2, 3])
y3 = np.array([4, 1, 1, 1])

plt.bar(x, y1, color='#d67ed0')
plt.bar(x, y2, color='#e6ad12', bottom=y1)
plt.bar(x, y3, color='#13c5ed', bottom=y1+y2)

plt.show()
```

Like "A"-Violet labeled as "2" on the plot

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to label each colored section is by using a legend. Assign a category to each color in the bar using the **label** argument in the **plt.bar** function. Then use the **plt.legend()** function at the end of the code to display the legend.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
y1 = np.array([2, 4, 5, 1])
y2 = np.array([1, 0, 2, 3])
y3 = np.array([4, 1, 1, 1])

# increase figure size
plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))

# add labels to each color
plt.bar(x, y1, color='#d67ed0', label = 'Cars')
plt.bar(x, y2, color='#e6ad12', bottom=y1, label = 'Buses')
plt.bar(x, y3, color='#13c5ed', bottom=y1+y2, label = 'Trains')
plt.legend(loc = 1, fontsize = 18)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I meant more like 
A, violet = 2
B, blue = 1
etc